# Change color implicit plot

Tags: python, plot, sympy

I have the following code:

```
import sympy as syp


x, y = syp.symbols('x, y')


Equation_1 = - 2*x + y**2 - 5
Equation_2 = x**3 + syp.sin(y) - 10


syp.plot_implicit(syp.Or(syp.Eq(Equation_1, 0), syp.Eq(Equation_2, 0)), (x, -50, 50), (y, -50, 50))
```

which provides this picture:

[image]

Do you know any hack that can be used to change the color of the second curve? I think it's not directly possible, according to Sympy's [documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/modules/plotting.html?highlight=plot_implicit#sympy.plotting.plot_implicit.plot_implicit).

Comment: I don't think it's implemented yet but I opened [this](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/2853) issue for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your hack, the `.extend()` method of Sympy's `Plot` objects

```
import sympy as syp
x, y = syp.symbols('x, y')

Eq0 = - 2*x + y**2 - 5
Eq1 = x**3 + syp.sin(y) - 10

p0 = syp.plot_implicit(Eq0, (x, -50, 50), (y, -50, 50), show=False)
p1 = syp.plot_implicit(Eq1, (x, -50, 50), (y, -50, 50), show=False, line_color='r')
p0.extend(p1)
p0.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I haven't used Sympy anymore since my (now 3 years old) question. That's why I haven't updated Sympy anymore on my old laptop. When I run your code, I still see two blue lines, so I guess this problem has been fixed in the most recent version of Sympy. I accept your answer, which can be useful for other programmers. Many thanks gboffi ;)

Answer (score 6):

It appears that passing any sort of color argument to the `plot_implicit` function is not currently implemented.
This is true regardless of how many functions you are plotting.
I suspect that it is possible to add this functionality, but it is not currently there.

On the other hand this can be done if you are only plotting lines.
Here's how:

```
import sympy as sy
x = sy.symbols('x')
# Make two plots with different colors.
p1 = sy.plot(x**2, (x, -1, 1), show=False, line_color='b')
p2 = sy.plot(x**3, (x, -1, 1), show=False, line_color='r')
# Make the second one a part of the first one.
p1.extend(p2)
# Display the modified plot object.
p1.show()
```

[image: A plot of two functions made using SymPy]

Comment: Thanks IanH, I already knew that with the function plot it is possible to change color, but unfortunately I don't have an explicit formula for my curve, so I need to use plot_implicit. If it's not possible to change color, I'll try a different solution, e.g. Maple.